# Trying to create a hyperlink with python

Tags: python, pandas, url, hyperlink, formatting

```
link = '<a href="https://google.com/{0}">{0}</a>'.format("search")
link
```

I do this and get this result as a string

```
'<a href="https://google.com/search">search</a>'
```

I just want to see the word "search" as the output. I will be converting this to a dataframe and only wish to see the word. As of now, I see the whole string even after writing back to excel.

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty.  If you're creating the link in the first place, as the title says, then obviously you already have the word `search` by itself, so why can't you just use it right then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of, related to, or helpful [creating hyperlinks in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452410/creating-hyperlinks-in-python)

Comment: Are you wanting to create hyperlinks in Excel? If so, see [Create Excel Hyperlinks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791441/create-excel-hyperlinks-in-python). Otherwise we are just guessing where you are stuck.

Comment: @davedwards, you are right, I am trying to create hyperlinks in excel. This excel already has data, formatted data, including dashboards and graphs. I tried using "openpyxl" for creating a new sheet with my hyperlinks, but it resets the whole workbook to loose formatting and graphs. I will try what you suggested in the above comment and update what happens here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read this: https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-and-viewing-html-files-with-python

Basically Python itself does not interpret HTML. If you work with Excel you may want to look at [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url)

Comment: I wanted to write the output in an excel file which already had data, and this data is formatted and has a few dashboards. I tried using "openpyxl" for creating a new sheet with my hyperlinks, but it resets the whole workbook to loose formatting and graphs. With "xlsxwriter" I can create the hyperlinks but unfortunately cannot save it back to the same excel file. I guess, I will just have to work with two workbooks for now. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you think it is right :)
If you think the web crawling is right, you might use bs4 or Selenium.
These are powerful web crawling tools for Python.
A tool that allows you to crawl the contents of a web page.
I'm a beginner too. This information may not be accurate. I hope you find it right.

you want more infomation or how to use -> [bs4 doc](https://%20https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://webpage.com')

soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

#do something useful
#prints all the links with corresponding text

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print link.get('href',None),link.get_text()
```