# Hyperlink strings in python dataframe

Tags: python

I need to hyperlink all the strings in a column with the matching URL from another column and compile the report in a excel format.

The data comes in the format below in a .csv file:

```css
Headline;URL
string1;https://www.url1
string2;https://www.url2
string3;https://www.url3
```

How can I use python to hyperlink the strings in the 'Headline' column with the matching URLs, delete the 'URL' column from the table and export it to an .xlsx file without losing the hyperlinks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791441/create-excel-hyperlinks-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Excel Hyperlinks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791441/create-excel-hyperlinks-in-python)