# Write Hyperlink and mask it by a word in Excel using Python win32com

Tags: python-3.x, excel, win32com

I am writing Hyperlink to excel using the recommendation below:

[Create Excel Hyperlinks in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791441/create-excel-hyperlinks-in-python/39791989?noredirect=1#comment115324264_39791989)

```
import win32com.client

excel = r'test.xlsx'

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excel)
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

for xlRow in range(1, 10, 1):
    worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor = worksheet.Range('A{}'.format(xlRow)),
                         Address="http://www.microsoft.com",
                         ScreenTip="Microsoft Web Site",
                         TextToDisplay="Microsoft")
 workbook.Save()
 workbook.Close()
```

I want the link to be masked by a text, for example "Microsoft". But instead I am getting this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have that problem, but I'll leave an answer here for future readers.
As you already figured out, the TextToDisplay-parameter does not work. But you can just set the cell value after inserting the hyperlink to the text you want it to show.
So your code would be

```
import win32com.client

excel = r'test.xlsx'

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excel)
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

for xlRow in range(1, 10, 1):
    worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor = worksheet.Range('A{}'.format(xlRow)),
                             Address="http://www.microsoft.com",
                             ScreenTip="Microsoft Web Site")
    # CHANGE IS HERE!!!
    worksheet.Cells(xlRow, 1).Value = "Microsoft"  
workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
```